# HTML Form won't transfer to PHP date

Tags: php, html, forms, unix, mktime

For some reason I can not get php to recognize a HTML form input as a date.

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form action="Input.php" method="post">
Depature Date: 
<select name="DMonth">
<option>- Select Month -</option>
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option value="03">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">June</option>
<option value="07">July</option>
<option value="08">August</option>
<option value="09">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select name="DDay">
<option>- Select Day -</option>
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
    <option value="04">4</option>
    <option value="05">5</option>
    <option value="06">6</option>
    <option value="07">7</option>
    <option value="08">8</option>
    <option value="09">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="DYear">
<option>- Select Year -</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
</select><br>
Departure Time: <select name="DHour" input type="number">
<option>- Select Hour -</option>
<option value="00">12 a.m.</option>
<option value="01">1 a.m.</option>
<option value="02">2 a.m.</option>
<option value="03">3 a.m.</option>
<option value="04">4 a.m.</option>
<option value="05">5 a.m.</option>
<option value="06">6 a.m.</option>
<option value="07">7 a.m.</option>
<option value="08">8 a.m.</option>
<option value="09">9 a.m.</option>
<option value="10">10 a.m.</option>
<option value="11">11 a.m.</option>
<option value="12">12 p.m.</option>
<option value="13">1 p.m.</option>
<option value="14">2 p.m.</option>
<option value="15">3 p.m.</option>
<option value="16">4 p.m.</option>
<option value="17">5 p.m.</option>
<option value="18">6 p.m.</option>
<option value="19">7 p.m.</option>
<option value="20">8 p.m.</option>
<option value="21">9 p.m.</option>
<option value="22">10 p.m.</option>
<option value="23">11 p.m.</option>
</select>
<select name="DMin">
<option>- Select Minute -</option>
<option value="00">00</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="45">45</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and the following PHP:

```
$DCity=(int) $_POST["DCity"];
$ACity=(int) $_POST["ACity"];
$DMonth=(int) $_POST["DMonth"];
$DDay=(int) $_POST["DDAY"];
$DYear=(int) $_POST["DYear"];
$DHour=(int) $_POST["DHour"];
$DMin=(int) $_POST["DMin"];
$DTime = mktime($DHour, $DMin, 0, $DMonth, $DDay, $DYear);
print date(DATE_RFC822, $DTime);
```

The return I should get from that should reflect whatever was entered into the form, however all that returns is the current date and time.
Is there an error in my code somewhere?? I've tried multiple methods of php time, but all return the current date NOT what was inputed in the HTML form.

Comment: Have you echoed out each $_POST variable (or `echo print_r($_POST, 1);`) to ensure that they are getting set properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) defaults each parameter as the current date/time. So it looks like your `$_POST` values aren't being set as expected, are empty, or are the wrong type.

According to [Converting to integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) you shouldn't need to explicitly cast at all, as the function expects `int`s anyhow. But doing the explicit cast or conversion will allow you to check if that is actually working prior to relying on the function call to do it for you (and in this case, possibly fail to do so).

You're using `(int)` to cast... What about using `intval()` instead or in addition, and then test/`print` the input values before your conversion, and then again after (before `mktime()`).

I expect you'll find they're not as expected, and if so, that your explicit casts are also failing.

Comment: @AnnHolley I appreciate the accept, but by the looks of your own answer, you solved this one by yourself! If my answer helped you debug your problem, then an upvote is appreciated, but really, I didn't spot the bug that you found so don't feel right taking the accept. It is perfectly valid to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a problem because some of the numbers start with a leading zero, which makes them octal. A number like 08 means nothing in octal.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  It was a simple mistake with capitalizations.  I have $_POST("DDAY") instead of $_POST("DDay") so it wasn't calling the "DDay" input from the HTML.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Did the answers here help you come to this conclusion? If so, you should upvote accordingly. Also, note that you are allowed to accept your own answer.

Comment: A good approach to help avoid this sort of issue is to not use "magic literals", rather, define constants and reuse these wherever the literal would be used. Eg in this case, 1. `define('KEY_DDAY', 'DDay');`   `2. ...<select name="'<?= KEY_DDAY ?>'"...`   3. `...=$_POST[KEY_DDAY];`.  This way, if you mistype the key name, you'll get an error rather than just unexpected behavior. Same goes for numbers, eg a constant named FILENAME_EXTENSION_LENGTH has more meaning in code than 3, and can be more easily redefined in future, rather than finding instances of 3 (that may actually be unrelated!)